# Discrete Approximation of Continuous Distribution, $P(X<Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I dont really get continuous probability, but we were introduced to it, and I'm struggling with this question:

Suppose $X \sim \text{Geometric}(p)$ and $Y \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ are independent and random variables. Find $P(X>Y)$

I know that for $X \sim \text{Geo}(p)$, $$P[X\ge i] = (1-p)^{i-1}$$ which means $$P[X<i] = 1- (1-p)^{i-1}$$ I also know that for $Y \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$, $$P[Y = k] = P[X = i] =(e^{-\lambda}) \lambda^i/i! $$

My guess is to create some kind of summation equivalent, but Im not sure how to set up and simplify it.

Maybe something like:
$$\sum\limits_{x}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{y}^{\infty} (1- (1-p)^{y-1})(e^{-x}) \lambda^x/x!$$

Am I on the right path? How do I set the limits for the summation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X>Y)=\sum_{i>j} P(X=i)P(Y=j)=\sum_{i>j} p(1-p)^{i-1} e^{-\lambda}\frac {\lambda^{j}} {j!}$. You can write this as $ \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{i=j+1}^{\infty} p(1-p)^{i-1} e^{-\lambda}\frac {\lambda^{j}} {j!}$. The inside sum is a geometric sum and its value is $(1-p)^{j}$. Finally you end with then series for $e^{\lambda (1-p)}$ multiplied by $e^{-\lambda}$ so the answer is $P(X>Y)=e^{-\lambda p}$.

Comment: oh I see! i think i missed what happened with the p though -- is it supposed to be $pe^{-λp}$?

Comment: @Melanie $\sum_j^{\infty} (1-p)^{i} =\frac {(1-p)^{j}} {1-(1-p)}=\frac {(1-p)^{j}} p$ so $p$ cancels.